# related rates (calculus) questions

Tags: calculus

1. The minute and hour hands of the GPO clock are 2m and 1.5m long respectively. How fast are their ends approaching at (a) 2 o'clock (b) 6 o'clock?
2. A fuel storage tank is in the shape of a right circular cone of base diameter 10m and height 20m and is being filled at a constant rate of 20m^3 per hour. FInd the rate at which the fuel level is rising at the instant when it is 8m deep.

Please help!

Comment: well for the first one I couldnt do at all and for the second one I do not know how to find the volume... they both are too confusing :(

Comment: can you explain 1st part little bit?

Comment: that is all... nothing is given further..sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For second part:
Volume of right circular cone $\;V=\dfrac 13\pi r^2 h$
Rate of volume increasing$\;\dfrac {dV}{dt}=20m^3/hour$

using similar triangle theorems we can find out radius when fuel is on 8 m height 
$$\Delta ABC\sim \Delta ADE$$
$$\dfrac {AB}{BC}=\dfrac {AD}{DE}$$
$$\dfrac{20}{5}=\dfrac {20-8}{r_1}$$
$$r_1=3$$

now rate of change in fuel height at height =8m.
We can think that there is a smaller cone of height 12m and radius=3m.

since $$V=\dfrac 13\pi r^2 h$$
$$\dfrac {dV}{dt}=\dfrac {d}{dt}(\dfrac 13\pi r^2 h)$$
$$20=\dfrac 13\pi 3^2 \dfrac {dh}{dt}$$
$$\dfrac {dh}{dt}=\dfrac {20}{3\pi} $$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

HINTS:

1) Think of a way to parametrize the motion of the end of each hand. To do this you need to consider how long the hands are as well as the speed they move at (speed is distance over time. Recall they are moving in circles around the clock). Then find a formula for the distance between the hands. Now use calculus to find the rate at which that distance changes.

2) Recall for a cone, $V_c=\frac{1}{3} \pi r^2 h$. Draw a diagram of what the fuel looks like when it is at a particular height $x$ and relate it to volumes of cones. Now by the chain rule, $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}F}=\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}V}\times\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}F}$ where $F$ is the volume of fuel poured.